# rowSums of alternating rows in a loop

Tags: r, rowsum

I have a dataframe called `Paper`on citations of papers for every year including their publication year as well as some meta stuff (journal, authors). It looks like:

```
Paper = read.table(textConnection("Meta Publication.Year X1999 X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003
A 1999 0 1 1 1 2
B 2000 0 0 3 1 0
C 2000 0 0 1 0 1
C 2001 0 0 0 1 5
D 1999 0 1 0 2 2"), header = TRUE)
```

I want to calculate the sum of citations two years after publication and append this list to `Paper`. However, I am not interested in every year, only those specified in a list `Years`. My steps (code below) were the following: Order `Paper` acc. `Publication.Year`, select `Publication.Year` and X-rows for first year (i.e. `X2000` and `X2001` for 1999), calculate sums, bind sums together, cbind to `Paper`.

Is there (more) elegant way to do this?

```
Years = as.numeric(c(1999, 2000))
Paper <- Paper[with(Paper, order(Paper[["Publication.Year"]])), ]
Two.Year = as.numeric()
for (i in Years){
Mat <- subset(Paper, Paper[["Publication.Year"]]==i, select=c("Publication.Year", paste("X", i+1, sep=""), paste("X", i+2, sep="")))
temp <- rowSums(Mat[,-1])
Two.Year <- c(Two.Year, temp)
rm(temp)
}
Paper <- cbind(Paper, Two.Year)
rm(Two.Year)
rm(Jahre)
Paper <- subset(Paper, select=c("Meta","Publication.Year","Two.Year")) # Because in the end I only need the citation number
```

Comment: Yes. See [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your years of interest change for each row, you're going to have to create new variables to indicate those years. Then you can use `mapply` to sum the correct numbers.

```
Paper$pubYear1 <- paste0("X", as.character(Paper$Publication.Year + 1))
Paper$pubYear2 <- paste0("X", as.character(Paper$Publication.Year + 2))
Paper$pubCount <- mapply(function(r, y1, y2) Paper[r, y1] + Paper[r, y2], 
  row.names(Paper), Paper$pubYear1, Paper$pubYear2)
```

Here's the resulting data frame:

```
> Paper
  Meta Publication.Year X1999 X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 pubYear1 pubYear2 pubCount
1    A             1999     0     1     1     1     2    X2000    X2001        2
2    B             2000     0     0     3     1     0    X2001    X2002        4
3    C             2000     0     0     1     0     1    X2001    X2002        1
4    C             2001     0     0     0     1     5    X2002    X2003        6
5    D             1999     0     1     0     2     2    X2000    X2001        1
```

Comment: Storing the names of the columns of interest is clever and way shorter than mine. But I wonder why my approach seems to be much faster: Yours took me 0.9238267 secs and mine only 0.175153 secs.

Comment: It's probably that the ```mapply``` function has so much indexing work to do for each row. Elegance ≠ speed, at least not in this case.